# Make size of the popup large enough to contain its element

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm on `RichFAces 4.5.2.Final, JSF 2.1`. I need to make a popupPanel auto-adjustable to any change of embedded textAreas. Let's consider the following markup:

```
<rich:popupPanel id="editMailingTemplatePopup"  autosized="true">
    <h:inputTextarea value="#{editMailingTemplateController.template.name}" maxlength="128" size="80" />
</rich:popupPanel>
```

When I try to change the size of the `textArea` the size of the popupPanel is not being changed in spite of setting `autosized` attribute to true. Is it a solvable problem within `JSF/RichFaces` context or I should write javascript code?

Comment: Your are not using `<h:inputTextarea>`. You mentioned `<h:inputText>` instead.

Comment: @Tiny I'm sorry. Just a typo.

Comment: You can change size of popup based on text area size (for example via javascript) or you can select the opposite way - prevent to change size of text area: `<h:inputTextarea value="#{form.text}" label="#{msg.notes}"
rows="10" cols="50" style="resize:none;">    <f:validateLength maximum="4000" />    </h:inputTextarea>`

Comment: How are you changing the size? The popupPanel listens to certain events to resize itself but if those aren't triggering it won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Following is works for me :

Add css as below :

```
.rf-pp-cnt-scrlr{
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
} 
.rf-pp-cntr{
 width: auto !important;
 height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that it's a good idea to override built-in rich-faces classes. Maybe I just don't undestand something...

Comment: Hey user, implementing build-in classes to fit your need are exactly what they are meant to... Hence the name _cascading_ style sheets; you don't override anything, you just add style to the chain... Whenever a property is used the closest definition to the actual element wins. So doing this is not bad practice.